# Error opening Anaconda package spykeviewer

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I am running Anaconda on macOS Sierra utilising Python 2.7. I want to be able to run spykeviewer https://anaconda.org/pypi/spykeviewer

however I keep receiving this error:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/becky/anaconda/envs/spykeviewer-en/bin/spykeviewer", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())

File "/Users/becky/anaconda/envs/spykeviewer-en/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spykeviewer/start.py", line 42, in main
    from ui.main_window_neo import MainWindowNeo

File "/Users/becky/anaconda/envs/spykeviewer-en/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spykeviewer/ui/main_window_neo.py", line 16, in <module>
    from spyderlib.widgets.variableexplorer.collectionseditor import \
ImportError: No module named spyderlib.widgets.variableexplorer.collectionseditor*
```

I have all of the dependent packages downloaded and I have reinstalled spyder as the error seems to be pointing to this module but I still get the same import error.

Here is how I installed the different packages:

```
conda install pyqt=4
conda install scipy
conda install gdata
conda install matplotlib
conda install pytables
conda install spyder
tables already installed in the environment
from terminal -> into guidata folder -> python setup.py install
from terminal -> into quiqwt -> python setup.py install
both are then in root —> open terminal in spykeviewer-en —> pip install guidata 
condo install cython
pip install guiqwt
pip install neo
pip install spykeutils
pip install spykeviewerenter
```

Comment: What version of `spyder` is installed? Can you try to install version 2.1.0, which seems to be the minimum version spykeviewer wants (http://spyke-viewer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#dependencies)? It's possible that a newer version of Spyder rearranged the modules, and `spykeviewer` can't find what it needs.

Comment: I have downgrade spyder, however I now get the following error:  File "/Users/becky/anaconda/envs/spykeviewer-en/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/qt/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    assert os.environ['QT_API'] in ('pyqt', 'pyside')
AssertionError

Comment: I'm not sure... you might have to investigate the dependencies of Spyder 2.1.0 and see what you need to install.